# Information about Smartstream Payroll tables

Tags: sql-server

I have looked  at  many sites for this but cannot find the answer….

I am trying to find information about  Smartstream Payroll tables.

I think there is some way to access the tables from Visual Basic but I am not sure.

Where can I find the table information?

Thank you,

Comment: Why did you tag your question as "JavaScript" and "SQL Server"?

Comment: I did not mean to...

Comment: The system can be run via sql server so I left that.